# Combining mongo::Query in c++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb

I'm using MongoDb's c++ driver and trying to combine mongo::Query classes along with JSON query as a string.

In my example i'm trying to combine q1,q2,q3. I can convert q3 to a mongo::fromjson(q3); in a try catch to catch unwanted errors before the final combine but i'm not sure if thats the best way to do it.

So far my only attempt is to use the BSON_ARRAY to combine the separate sections but that is still not coming out the way I want (understably though).

```
///The output im trying to achieve is:
// {a : 1,b : 2, c : 3}

const mongo::Query q1 = QUERY("a" << 1);
const mongo::Query q2 = QUERY("b" << 2);
const std::string q3 = "{c : 3}";

// Attempt 1. I know it does not work.
mongo::Query qAll = BSON_ARRAY(q1.toString() << q2.toString());

std::cout << q1.toString() << std::endl;
// Outputs { a: 1 } as expected

std::cout << q2.toString() << std::endl;
// Outputs { b: 2 } as expected

std::cout << qAll.toString() << std::endl;
// Outputs { 0: "{ a: 1 }", 1: "{ b: 2 }" }, expected but wrong.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really avoid using a BSONObjBuilder that I see, but you can make life a bit easier on yourself by making better use of the API that BSONObjBuilder gives you:

```
const mongo::Query q1 = QUERY("a" << 1);
const mongo::Query q2 = QUERY("b" << 2);
const std::string q3 = "{c : 3}";

mongo::BSONObjBuilder builder;
builder.appendElements(q1.getFilter());
builder.appendElements(q2.getFilter());
builder.appendElements(mongo::fromjson(q3));
const mongo::Query qAll(builder.obj());

std::cout << qAll.toString() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Well, its a little cleaner Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well so far this is the most elegant way I've came up with so far, any thoughts/suggestions?

```
mongo::Query combineQueries(const mongo::Query q1, const mongo::Query q2) {
    mongo::BSONObjBuilder obAll;
    mongo::BSONObjIterator ii = q1.getFilter().begin();
    while (ii.more()) {
        obAll.append(ii.next());
    }

    ii = q2.getFilter().begin();
    while (ii.more()) {
        obAll.append(ii.next());
    }

    return obAll.obj();
}
```